# DataTables Pager Showing Many Pages when there is Only One

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

This is a weird one.
I'm using datatables v1.10.19 with jQuery 3.3.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

My datatables grid is configured to display 1000 records (but you can change it to 2500, 5000 and "all").
I've only got about 60 records in my database.

It is using Server-Side processing to retrieve data.

When the grid loads, the pager displays 5 buttons plus an ellipses (as if there is even more).

And even weirder, if I change the drop-down to display "all" records, it acts as I would expect i.e. the pager has 1 page button.

The payloads are pretty much identical:

```
{
    "data": {
        "draw": 8,
        "recordsTotal": 86,
        "recordsFiltered": 66,
        "data": [rows of data here]
    },
    "outcome": {
        "opResult": "Success",
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

When you click on page 2, it does successfully retrieve a payload with 0 rows. 
But there shouldn't be a page 2 available on the pager.

The config object for the datatable looks like this:

```
    eventsSvr.buildConfig = function (url) {
        return {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            //"paging": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: url,
                type: ajax.requestPOST,
                dataSrc: 'data.data' // the path in the JSON structure to the array which will be the rows.
            },
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "lengthMenu": [[1000, 2500, 5000, -1], [1000, 2500, 5000, "All"]],
            "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                eventsSvr.searchTextSpan.text('Search').removeClass('search-is-on');
            },
            "columns": eventsSvr.grid.columns,
            "columnDefs": eventsSvr.grid.columnDefs,
            dom: 'ltp'
        };
```

I do have a bunch of custom searches on the page, so I've had to write a lot of code like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var picker3 = $(eventsSvr.datePickerInputs[0]).data(icapp.kendoKey);
        var picker4 = $(eventsSvr.datePickerInputs[1]).data(icapp.kendoKey);
        var rowStartDate = moment(data[3], icapp.date.momentParseFormat).toDate();
        var rowEndDate = moment(data[4], icapp.date.momentParseFormat).toDate();

        ... etc.
    }
);
```

But the odd thing is the different behavior as between "All" records vs 1000 records.
As described above, select "All" records works (resulting in just 1 page button), but none of the other paging sizes work (i.e. 1000, 2500, 5000). The data for the 1 page does return, but I get 5 page buttons and an ellipses.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using server-side processing mode DataTables expects `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` to be root-level elements. Consider changing your repsonse to the following and you can remove `dataSrc` option.

```
{
    "draw": 8,
    "recordsTotal": 86,
    "recordsFiltered": 66,
    "data": [rows of data here],
    "outcome": {
        "opResult": "Success",
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can manipulate the response before passing it to DataTables using function supplied as value for `dataSrc` option, but I would recommend keep things according to expected format for more readable code.

Comment: OK Cool. Thanks. I will try that today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks. Pity. It would have been cool if the `dataSrc` property handled that. Now I have to make a special exception in my server-side framework, rather than wrapping my response in an `ApiResponse` object like all other API responses. I can live with that. DataTables is worth it! Cheers.

Comment: @onefootswill, you can solve it with `dataSrc` as I wrote it in the second paragraph. Let me know if you prefer to keep the response as is and I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah cool. That's fair enough. Thanks again for solving the problem for me.

Comment: I just wanted to return to this ticket to update with the info that I actually did not get this working. I've no idea why, but the Pager buttons just go out of sync with the rest of the grid when I filter and get back a number of rows which is less than the page size. Still seeing buttons which number up to 49 (after the ellipsis).

Comment: @onefootswill, did you change the response structure as I recommended in my answer?

Comment: I did and it seems to be working now. It got confused as our tester raised this bug (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716362/datatables-pager-showing-one-page-when-there-are-many) and I broke it trying to fix that. I guess we will see if the tester finds another issue.

Comment: @onefootswill, answered your other question as well.