# DataTables Pager Showing One Page when there Are Many

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a problem, which was originally set out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59514278/540156). I thought it was working, but not so.

I'm using datatables v1.10.19 with jQuery 3.3.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

Now, my problem is that regardless of how many pages of data I have, the pager is showing one paging button (as if all the data fits on 1 page, when it doesn't).

My config object looks like this:

```
        {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: url,
                type: ajax.requestPOST
            },
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "lengthMenu": [[-1, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000], ["All", 500, 1000, 2500, 5000]],
            "columns": eventsSvr.grid.columns,
            "columnDefs": eventsSvr.grid.columnDefs,
            "language": $.extend({}, appDt.loadingSpinner, appDt.lengthMenuText),
            dom: 'ltp'
        }
```

My return payload looks like this:

```
{
    "draw": 4,
    "recordsTotal": 3727,
    "recordsFiltered": 500,
    "data": [ big data array here ]
}
```

As can be seen the data has 3700+ rows.
The page size is 500.
Yet, the grid only has 1 page. It has 500 rows and there are no buttons on the pager to move to any subsequent pages.

So, the user can only view the first 500 records.

Any ideas as to what is going on with the pager?

Comment: I think I may have figured this out. Both `recordsFiltered` and `recordsTotal` should be the same i.e. the total number of records. I was setting `recordsFiltered` to the size of the page. Seems a bit odd to have 2 variables which repeat a value. That's why I'm not sure that this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables calculates number of pages based on `recordsFiltered` and your page size. It contains total number of records after filtering has been applied.

When search is performed, `recordsFiltered` may not be equal to `recordsTotal`.

Your server-side handler should calculate total number of records without applying the search criteria and return it in `recordsTotal` and then calculate total number of records after applying the search criteria and return it in `recordsFiltered`.

This allows DataTables to display in the information section the following message:

> Showing 1 to 10 of `recordsFiltered` entries (filtered from`recordsTotal` total entries)

You can read more about proper format of the returned data in server-side processing mode in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Comment: yeah, I originally had the code like you said. But that led to the bug my tester reported, which I have asked about here. Server-side paging is like playing whack-a-mole :) You do one thing, it breaks another. Hopefully the current code has got it working.